# Aptana Studio 3 Rails 2.x debugging broken?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, aptana

I'm running Aptana Studio 3 on Windows XP with Ruby 1.8.7, and I cannot get the integrated debugger to work (from app explorer view, running commands->debug server)

I have installed the rubyInstaller DevKit, and the ruby-debug-base, and ruby-debug-ide gems.  Here is the error I am seeing whenever I attempt to invoke 'debug server'

```
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.16, ruby-debug-base 0.10.4) listens on 127.0.0.1:4725
Fatal exception in DebugThread loop: The requested service provider could not be loaded or initialized. - socket(2)
Backtrace:
C:/ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:135:in `initialize'
  from: C:/ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:135:in `new'
  from: C:/ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:135:in `start_control'
  from: C:/ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:129:in `initialize'
  from: C:/ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:129:in `new'
  from: C:/ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:129:in `start_control'
  from: C:/ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:96:in `start_server'
  from: C:/ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:100:in `debug_program'
  from: C:/ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/bin/rdebug-ide:87
  from: C:/ruby/Ruby187/bin/rdebug-ide:19:in `load'
  from: C:/ruby/Ruby187/bin/rdebug-ide:19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by a bug in Studio 3: http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-2548

The bug should be fixed in the 3.0.2 release. Also, the link Christopher attached did have details on this issue, including a user's workaround posted near the end of the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I opened a discussion for this in the Aptana support forum

https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/2896-issues-with-aptana-30-radrails

RadRails 2's rails debugger still works just fine so I switched to that.